# MySQL return possible pairs from columns

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
Name | Surname | Gender
John | A       |  M
Anna | B       |  F
Sam  | C       |  M
Lisa | D       |  F
```

Now I would like to return all possible combinations of pairs, with the restriction that each name should not pair with itself. In addition I would like to display information about whether both pairs share the same gender or not.

As such, the output should look as follows

```
Pair           | Same gender?
John A, Anna B | No
John A, Sam C  | Yes
...            | ...
Lisa D, Sam C  | No
```

How would I do that in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a [cross join](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php) in mysql like this:

```
SELECT
    a.`name`
    , b.name
    ,
    CASE
        WHEN a.gender != b.gender
        THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END as 'Same Gender'
FROM
    gender a
    , gender b
WHERE a.name != b.name
```

And if you want to "Pair" up the columns like your question, you can do the column like this:

```
CONCAT(a.`name`, ', ', b.`name`) AS 'Pair'
```

To answer your comment you can do it like this:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(a.`name`, ', ', b.`name`) AS 'Pair'
    , mi_a.stuff
    , mi_b.stuff
    ,
    CASE
        WHEN a.gender != b.gender
        THEN 'No'
        ELSE 'Yes'
    END AS 'Same Gender'
FROM
    test.gender a
    CROSS JOIN test.gender b
    JOIN test.`more_info` mi_a ON mi_a.gender_id = a.id
    JOIN test.`more_info`  mi_b ON mi_b.gender_id = b.id
WHERE a.name != b.name
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So my first table is the result of a joined table as such: select name, surname, gender from person
join info
 on person.id = info.id. How would i include that in your statement? Do i need to define it as a and b seperately?

Comment: Thank you very much! how do i define the test table in the FROM part? i get an error telling me it cant find test.gender :S

Comment: @AaronDT this is just a sample query. I build a couple of tables on a test database to make sure the query worked before giving you the answer. Just change the tables, and database to what you are using and you should be good to go :). So if your database is called aaron, then you would do aaron.my_table_name

Comment: @AaronDT a is just an alias, so test.gender could be called gender, g, a, bob or anything you want to identify it. I'm off work now, so I won't be on for several hours. Good luck to you!